# jQuery UI Autocomplete onFocus or OnBlur event

Tags: jquery-ui

I am referring the following url http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox
to render comboBoxes in my HTML page. Using the following line of code I can determine when an item from the comboBox is selected.

```
       $("#myDropDown").combobox({
            select: function (event, ui) {

               //item from combobox is selected
            },
        });
```

I wish to attach an onFocus or an onBlur event to this dropdown. On searching I only come across the select event. Is there a workaround to bind an onFocus or an onBlur event to the comboBox?

Comment: I think you can trigger the focus event on the input created in the ui widget http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood#javascript-5

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus